# Compare data and if there exist same data for several row then mention the rule as parameter

Tags: blueprism

I have data in collection, task is to check for multiple column with certain rules.
For example: if Username column and employee ID matches then check for duplicates, if there exist a match then need to make note of the duplicate values and in output column write R1.
Then next step is to check Username with employee wage then check for duplicates, if there exist a match then need to make note of the duplicate values and in output column write R2.
Now need to append both the rules in one data item.
How to i do all the rules check by using collection filter and update the output values to the same collection?

Comment: What tools are you using to solve this problem? What have you done until now?

Comment: In Automation Blueprism

Comment: This is pretty basic Blue Prism functionality. If you don't know how to approach this I would recommend re-visiting some of the more foundational literature from Blue Prism itself, like the Foundation Training guide.

Answer (score 0):

For this approach. I would suggest you to use "Collection Manipulation VBO"

1. Create the extra columns which are needed : "Append Field" keep value as blank, we will update the values later
2. Filter collection according to the data, then check the values and add the values into the appended new column.